# Can't read a number from file

Tags: c

```
FILE*f;
if ((f = fopen("tester.bin", "rb"))==NULL)
{
    printf("File cannot be opened");
    exit(1);
}

int *Number_Filep = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
fread(*(Number_Filep), sizeof(int), 1,f);
 printf("%d", *Number_Filep);
FILE*fp;
if ((fp = fopen("Data.txt", "w"))==NULL)
{
    printf("File cannot be opened");
    exit(1);
}
fprintf(fp,"Age: %d", *(Number_Filep));
fclose(fp);
free(Number_Filep);
fclose(f);
```

In the file, the number is 5, but when I run the console application, it shows a random big number. How to fix it, so that it reads the correct number?

Comment: The first argument to `fread` is supposed to be a pointer. You''re dereferencing your pointer (`Number_Filep`) in the call though. This is probably not what you want to do.

Comment: Well, I removed the dereferencing of (Number_Filep), but the problem persists

Comment: In addition to the other issues mentioned are your sure you know the C data type contents of the file?  You do appear to be treating it as binary data given the "rb", however along with that must come information about the size of the integer (e.g. char, short, int, long, long long).  Are you sure it was written as binary data of size int?

Comment: Actually, it turned out to be an 'unsigned' variable, not int. Now it works. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fread`'s first argument [is a pointer](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/), but you're calling it like this:

```
fread(*(Number_Filep), sizeof(int), 1,f);
```

...so the first argument is `*(Number_Filep)` - an integer. This is not what you wanted to do.

You should read like this:

```
fread(Number_Filep, sizeof(int), 1,f);
```